# Can we do manipulation with Data stored in Azure Storage directly through VM without downloading it on VM?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I had some data that is stored on Azure Storage which is in compressed form and i want to decompress it so is it possible that i could decompress it without downloading it on the Virtual Machine. I mean to say that the storage could work in the same manner as my Secondary storage device does. Ask if you need more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is always "depends".

If it is possible - yes. Do you really want to do it - I am not sure.

Take the Blob Storage, because I assume you store your data in a blob storage. There are two different types of Blobs - [Block Blobs and Page Blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx). Either can be updated by partially updating its content.

When having a block blob you can modify it using the [Put Block operation on the Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx). When you have a page blob, you can use the [Put Page operation on the Blob Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691975.aspx).
Of course after modifying the content you will have to send a final request to the Blob Service API to "commit" the changes and inform the service about the new content ([Put Block List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179467.aspx) for BlockBlobs and implement robust retry logic for Put Page for Page blobs).

Although technically it is possible to manipulate the content on the blob without downloading the whole file, it really brings more complications than it solves. For example - once you modify part of the content of a file, all the checksums are now broken. Moreover - if it is a compressed file, you also have to modify the header of the file. At the end - if you know the exact structure of what you saved and you know which exact parts of it you want to modify - you can do it. But I think it will be just overengineering.

Comment: so in any case i have download some chunk and handle it all by myself it cannot be done in the same way as being done if the file was stored locally and i could read it using some file reader inside the code?

Comment: @astaykov is it possible with Azure Files to make your blob lik a Share - like SMB share - and then edit the files with regular .net streams? Like [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) which was anounce [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-azure-smb-file-sharing-service)

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov, Azure files is in Preview, and frankly I wouldn't bother. Because even with Azure files - the content comes to your server. If the requirement is explicit to not have the whole content on the server, the only approach to be crazy working with API .... Azure Files IMO is a step back in the Cloud thinking. Call me an old-schooler, but I would only work with Blobs ...

Comment: @astaykov I agree with you. The direct manipulation of files sounds spooky to me :)

Comment: I said - you have know the structure of the file very very well in to manipulate just portions of it ;) and I didn't say that I would do this :)